# How to test plymouth via virtual machine?

Tags: plymouth, virtualization, testing, openssh

I am trying to edit my splash screen but its really annoying to restart the computer everytime just to find out it doesn't even work. i read on an article that I can do a virtual machine via ssh but I have no idea how to do that. I installed ubuntu in VirtualBox yesterday now installing `sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client` on it. Now I am supposed to access the machine as root and test splash on tty1, and I have no idea how to do that. I tried searching around but there isn't a lot of information regarding Plymouth testing on the web.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You cannot test plymouth in VirtualBox because the display driver does not create a special device (`/dev/dri/card0` to be exact), neither is it possible to display such a graphical thing in a terminal using SSH.

Comment: ohh i didn't know that, thanks. so what is ssh used for what are the reasons people use it?

Comment: SSH provides a console in which commands can be entered. Although SSH can forward GUI (it's called X Forwarding), SSH is mainly used for entering commands directly. See also [What is the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need VirtualBox for that. You can test themes within a session.

- Install the package `plymouth-x11`
- Run `sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; sleep 10 ; sudo killall plymouthd`

This will show you how your theme would look like on two screens (actually a simulation of multi-monitor setups) for 10 seconds. You can add the different actions you want to test (see `plymouth --help`) between the --show-splash and sleep command.

Comment: i tried this command last time and it just loged me out, looks like i was missing the plymouth-x11 package. thanx it worked this time but the window was blank. ill have to reinstall the splash i guess.

Comment: ya it works now although I get 2 screens and in the splah the logo and spinning arrows are out of not aligned. and i didnt see the progress bar. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know what theme you are testing. There's no progress bar or spinning arrows in Ubuntu's default theme.

Comment: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ubuntu+10.4+and+10.10+Plymouth+Splash?content=128607 this is the splash I am trying to imporve to my liking at the momment the only thing i changed in the script file was to slow down the spinning of the logo.

Comment: @Vitaly The Plymouth theme only updates when you click or press a modifier key (CTRL, ALT, SHIFT, etc.). I know, weird.