# background image for when I enter encryption password

Tags: encryption, plymouth

Any idea how to change the background image on the screen, where you enter **encryption password**? It's the noise-texture by default, the same as the default login screen background. Very dull.

I am running 19.10.

Image of the screen in question:

[image]

Essentially, when you are installing Ubuntu, you can choose to encrypt the whole HDD. If you do this, you will get this screen before the OS starts loading. I would like to change the this dull background to some custom image.

Comment: @PRATAP yup, give me few minutes

Comment: correct, as per my description under the image

Comment: It's not, this one I have already custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***OS: Ubuntu 19.10***

Ok.. I have Cleared my SSD and done it from scratch to see if it works?

the background color/ look is from the Plymouth theme.. so you need to install the Plymouth theme that fits you.

There are lot if you google.. for example: https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/108/page/8/ord/latest/

For testing purpose I used this Plymouth theme.. https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1294920/

a short video of the result.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFJLc.jpg

***NOTE: Be careful with the compatibility of the Plymouth theme you are going to use.***

---

Here are the steps..

1. Download the theme.
2. copy it to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/` # here "mint-galaxy" is the directory in my case.

[image]

3. Install the theme with the below..

Command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/mint-galaxy/mint-galaxy.plymouth 9999
```

4. Select the theme with the below..

Command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Choose the number belongs to the theme we want.. type the number and press enter..

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth 
[sudo] password for pratap: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/mint-galaxy/mint-galaxy.plymouth   100       auto mode
* 1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/mint-galaxy/mint-galaxy.plymouth   100       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth   100       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

5. update the initramfs with the below..

Command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Here at step 5 we will notice Information to set the RESUME Variable.. until we set this variable `update-initramfs -u` command will not get success..

So how to make the RESUME variable?

note down the info from step 5 which gives you the path..

6. to know the UUID of that path.. run `sudo blkid`

example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for pratap: 
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: UUID="ugg6wW-5d3T-7iMb-vKep-lzLJ-Jyfw-pCPMDH" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: UUID="5a53e741-abcf-464e-866f-3d32c231ed7a" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: UUID="2e51d644-c62c-4fb1-98b0-f451cc6d7191" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="af10b57f-1188-4129-be36-d8c1471827c7" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="4d0e01c9-d3e7-4c33-8f90-ba8d3b14b5ec"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="CDA8-B894" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="e6148d22-a32e-4c0e-b8b8-3f4dc6842059"
/dev/sda2: UUID="b05c41d5-ef6c-43a6-ace4-ac76123c643c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6563ffaa-2855-4682-8d37-17b6702923e9"
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

the line required in my case is

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: UUID="5a53e741-abcf-464e-866f-3d32c231ed7a" TYPE="swap"
```

7. now create a text file named  `resume` with below content and place it in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/` # Your UUID will be different. Change it in below.

Content:

```
RESUME=UUID=5a53e741-abcf-464e-866f-3d32c231ed7a
```

[image]

8. now run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and this time this command should run successfully with out any Information/ errors.
9. Reboot to see the Plymouth theme.

---

Images of Peter-Rabbit Plymouth Theme..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works well, but how do you know the compatibility? E.g. the [highest voted Theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1009736/) does not work. Age might be an indicator, but how to really know? I removed it using `sudo update-alternatives --remove default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/Earth-sunrise/Earth-sunrise.plymouth`

Comment: @pLumo.. nice point.. https://askubuntu.com/q/51078/739431

Comment: wow.. thanks a lot for all the effort. I will play with this as soon as I have time

Comment: What is "  0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/mint-galaxy/mint-galaxy.plymouth   100       auto mode"? Have you tested it on Ubuntu? Linux Mint is not Ubuntu. What is the output from Ubuntu?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the effort and most of all giving me the name 'Plymouth' - no, I didn't know it :) This opens the doors to so many new features. +1 ofc.