# No Plymouth in Video Card Intel mobile 945GME

Tags: 10.10, intel-graphics, plymouth

Recently, i have installed Maverick in my old netbook with Intel mobile 945GME Video Card, work flawlessly, but the problem is **plymouth**.

When i boot up my netbook, the plymouth **not start** it just **black screen** then GNOME desktop appear.

Sometime there are text shown (i'm not Understand the purpose of the text, it like login in "text mode" when we press Ctrl+Alt+F1 but after second (without typing anything), GNOME desktop appear) then sometime Plymouth shown (but rare) in short duration (the plymouth even shown only in 1 second)

I'm try set the resolution from GRUB, no result.

Your Help Really Apreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution that works for several intel integrated graphics types:

In a terminal:

```
sudo su
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
update-initramfs -u
exit
```

Comment: @rizanoar - please mark the answer as accepted and vote on it if it was useful to you.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `sudo apt-get install startupmanager` then changing the resolution and tick on the show boot splash.

Then make sure the right plymouth theme is selected:

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` then choose the one that you want
and then `sudo update-initramfs -u`

try checking `/etc/default/grub` and make sure the splash is enabled `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"`

If you would like to customize your Plymouth theme check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50757/how-to-get-plymouth-to-display-boot-messages-when-booting) out.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: not work, black screen still appear with "conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA" Message shown.