# How to enable plymouth bootscreen animation?

Tags: 10.04, boot, acer, plymouth, aspire-one

My netbook, running Lucid, can't display bootscreen animation. I want to know how to enable it.

My netbook is Acer Aspire One D260. Intel Atom N450, 1GB RAM and GMA 3150.

I know a tool called rcconf able to turns on/off services using the scripts in
`/etc/init.d/`. I thought maybe plymouth can be initialized there but I'm not really sure and I don't how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: probably your system is not enough to handle it,please give your spes please

Comment: Yes, I already adding the specs. I appreciate your response.

Comment: slightly different intel graphics chip - but possibly this Q&A will help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/51803/no-plymouth-in-video-card-intel-mobile-945gme

Comment: @fossfreedom I did as you told but It's not work for me. Are there another way to solve it? Can we use rcconf? Because when I run rcconf I can see in terminal that plymouth is unchecked but I have no idea how to check it. what it does anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it disabled, helps your computer to boot faster. It can be enabled and customized from **Plymouth manager**, which you can install from Ubuntu Software Center.